# ensime server fails to start from emacs

Tags: emacs, ensime

I am starting a new project in scala. I use emacs as editor.

So far it cannot be more simple. This is the build.sbt

```
name := "Sampler"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
```

I have run the ensimeConfig command in sbt (0.13 version)

When I start ensime on Emacs (M-ensime) I get the following error:

```
13:34:52.511 ERROR None Server - There was a problem parsing /home/jeronimo/prog/coursera/progfun2/circuits/.ensime
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shapeless.DataT$.genTraversableDataT(Lshapeless/Lazy;Lscala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom;)Lshapeless/DataT;
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$anon$default$macro$337$1.inst$macro$320$lzycompute(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$anon$default$macro$337$1.inst$macro$320(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$anon$default$macro$337$1$$anonfun$inst$macro$319$1.apply(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$anon$default$macro$337$1$$anonfun$inst$macro$319$1.apply(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at shapeless.Lazy$$anon$1.value$lzycompute(lazy.scala:121)
    at shapeless.Lazy$$anon$1.value(lazy.scala:121)
    at shapeless.EverywhereAux$$anonfun$default$2.apply(sybclass.scala:184)
    at shapeless.Cases$Case1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(cases.scala:40)
    at shapeless.Cases$Case1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(cases.scala:38)
    at shapeless.PolyDefns$Case.apply(poly.scala:37)
    at shapeless.DataT$$anon$12.gmapT(sybclass.scala:144)
    at shapeless.DataT$$anon$12.gmapT(sybclass.scala:142)
    at shapeless.DataT$$anon$12.gmapT(sybclass.scala:144)
    at shapeless.DataT$$anon$12.gmapT(sybclass.scala:142)
    at shapeless.DataT1$$anon$9.gmapT(sybclass.scala:116)
    at shapeless.EverywhereAux$$anonfun$default$2.apply(sybclass.scala:184)
    at shapeless.Cases$Case1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(cases.scala:40)
    at shapeless.Cases$Case1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(cases.scala:38)
    at shapeless.PolyDefns$Case.apply(poly.scala:39)
    at org.ensime.core.Canonised$.apply(Canon.scala:19)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$.validated(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$$anonfun$3.apply(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:44)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$$anonfun$3.apply(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$.validated(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:44)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$.parse(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:32)
    at org.ensime.server.Server$.main(Server.scala:120)
    at org.ensime.server.Server.main(Server.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shapeless.DataT$.genTraversableDataT(Lshapeless/Lazy;Lscala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom;)Lshapeless/DataT;
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$anon$default$macro$337$1.inst$macro$320$lzycompute(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$anon$default$macro$337$1.inst$macro$320(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$anon$default$macro$337$1$$anonfun$inst$macro$319$1.apply(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$anon$default$macro$337$1$$anonfun$inst$macro$319$1.apply(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at shapeless.Lazy$$anon$1.value$lzycompute(lazy.scala:121)
    at shapeless.Lazy$$anon$1.value(lazy.scala:121)
    at shapeless.EverywhereAux$$anonfun$default$2.apply(sybclass.scala:184)
    at shapeless.Cases$Case1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(cases.scala:40)
    at shapeless.Cases$Case1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(cases.scala:38)
    at shapeless.PolyDefns$Case.apply(poly.scala:37)
    at shapeless.DataT$$anon$12.gmapT(sybclass.scala:144)
    at shapeless.DataT$$anon$12.gmapT(sybclass.scala:142)
    at shapeless.DataT$$anon$12.gmapT(sybclass.scala:144)
    at shapeless.DataT$$anon$12.gmapT(sybclass.scala:142)
    at shapeless.DataT1$$anon$9.gmapT(sybclass.scala:116)
    at shapeless.EverywhereAux$$anonfun$default$2.apply(sybclass.scala:184)
    at shapeless.Cases$Case1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(cases.scala:40)
    at shapeless.Cases$Case1$$anon$1$$anonfun$1.apply(cases.scala:38)
    at shapeless.PolyDefns$Case.apply(poly.scala:39)
    at org.ensime.core.Canonised$.apply(Canon.scala:19)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$.validated(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:61)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$$anonfun$3.apply(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:44)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$$anonfun$3.apply(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:273)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$.validated(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:44)
    at org.ensime.config.EnsimeConfigProtocol$.parse(EnsimeConfigProtocol.scala:32)
    at org.ensime.server.Server$.main(Server.scala:120)
    at org.ensime.server.Server.main(Server.scala)

Process *inferior-ensime-server-circuits* exited abnormally with code 1
```

Comment: Just a quick comment. Whatever happened, it affects all my other projects!
I don't remember updating anything (scala, sbt or java)

Answer (score 0):

After trying to delete the .ivy2 cache without success I fixed the issue re-installing the EMACS ensime plugin.